# D3 simple drop down menu on click

Tags: d3.js

I cant find a straight forward answer anywhere. How can I make a drop down menu appear on click of an svg circle? I dont want it on display until the shape has been clicked. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 6):

Download this and include in your html : https://github.com/patorjk/d3-context-menu

And to use on click of a circle :

```
circle.on('contextmenu', d3.contextMenu(menu)); // attach menu to element
```

Thats if you want plugins :)

EDIT

NO PLUGINS

If you don't want plugins just create a list of things you want to show, prevent the default behaviour and on right click show the created list and click anywhere else hide it.

Here is a fiddle (not mine) : http://jsfiddle.net/thatoneguy/u2kJq/727/

List he creates :

```
<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action = "first">First thing</li>
  <li data-action = "second">Second thing</li>
  <li data-action = "third">Third thing</li>
</ul>
```

This will show on right click. Now to implement this with D3 you can use `event.preventDefault();` like the fiddle above, you have to use  `d3.event.preventDefault();`. Also you have to position the menu, so change the css top and left to position on mouse position :

```
 css({
      top: d3.event.pageY + "px",
      left: d3.event.pageX + "px"
    });
```

Here is a simple implementation of what I have described :

```js
var w = 500;
var h = 50;

var dataset = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25];

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("circle");

circles.attr("cx", function(d, i) {
    return (i * 50) + 25;
  })
  .attr("cy", h / 2)
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .on("contextmenu", function(event) {

    // Avoid the real one
   d3.event.preventDefault();

    // Show contextmenu
    $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).

    // In the right position (the mouse)
    css({
      top: d3.event.pageY + "px",
      left: d3.event.pageX + "px"
    });
  });;




//$(document).bind


// If the document is clicked somewhere
$(document).bind("mousedown", function(e) {

  // If the clicked element is not the menu
  if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {

    // Hide it
    $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
  }
});


// If the menu element is clicked
$(".custom-menu li").click(function() {

  // This is the triggered action name
  switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {

    // A case for each action. Your actions here
    case "first":
      alert("first");
      break;
    case "second":
      alert("second");
      break;
    case "third":
      alert("third");
      break;
  }

  // Hide it AFTER the action was triggered
  $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
});
```

```css
.custom-menu {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.custom-menu li {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #DEF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<body>
<ul class='custom-menu'>
  <li data-action = "first">First thing</li>
  <li data-action = "second">Second thing</li>
  <li data-action = "third">Third thing</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

If you want to do something when clicking one of the menu items, you can use `onclick` in the html like so :

```
<li onclick='doSomething()' data-action = "third">Third thing</li>
```

Or you can just give the individual items an id like so :

```
<li id='listItemOne' data-action = "third">Third thing</li>
```

And then add event listener :

```
document.getElementById('listItemOne').addEventListener('click', doSomething)
```

Comment: Ok I will look into that thank you, is there a way I could do it without a plugin just in d3? or are plugins more commonly used for this kind of thing? thanks again for response @thisOneGuy

Comment: @thisOneGuy, great answer.

Comment: @thisOneGuy thank you so much this has really got me heading in the right direction really appreciate it!

Answer (score 5):

@thisOneGuy gave a great answer, but since I've already coded it, here's a solution that builds the context menu with `svg`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.4.6" data-semver="3.4.6" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.6/d3.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    svg {
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <script>
    var menu = [{
      title: 'A really, really long item',
      action: function(elem, d, i) {
        console.log('Item #1 clicked!');
        console.log('The data for this circle is: ' + d);
      }
    }, {
      title: 'Item #2',
      action: function(elem, d, i) {
        console.log('You have clicked the second item!');
        console.log('The data for this circle is: ' + d);
      }
    }]

    var data = [1, 2, 3];

    var g = d3.select('body').append('svg')
      .on('click', function(){
        m.style('display', 'none');
      })
      .attr('width', 500)
      .attr('height', 400)
      .append('g');

    g.selectAll('circles')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('circle')
      .attr('r', 30)
      .attr('fill', 'steelblue')
      .attr('cx', function(d) {
        return 100;
      })
      .attr('cy', function(d) {
        return d * 100;
      })
      .on('contextmenu', function(d) {
        var coors = d3.mouse(this);

        m.attr('transform', 'translate(' + coors[0] + ',' + coors[1] + ')');
        m.style('display', 'block');
        m.datum(d);

        d3.event.preventDefault();
      });
    
    /* build context menu */
    var m = g.append("g")
      m.style('display', 'none');

    var r = m.append('rect')
      .attr('height', menu.length * 25)
      .style('fill', "#eee");

    var t = m.selectAll('menu_item')
      .data(menu)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
        return 'translate(' + 10 + ',' + ((i + 1) * 20) + ')';
      })
      .on('mouseover', function(d){
        d3.select(this).style('fill', 'steelblue');
      })
      .on('mouseout', function(d){
        d3.select(this).style('fill', 'black');
      })
      .on('click', function(d,i){
        d.action(d, d3.select(this.parentNode).datum(), i);
      })
      .append('text')
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.title;
      });
    
    var w = 0;
    t.each(function(d){
      var l = this.getComputedTextLength();
      if (l > w) w = l;
    })
    r.attr('width', w + 20);  
  
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Apologies :L I know how annoying it is when someone answers the same question when you spend time coding an answer yourself :)

Comment: @thisOneGuy, no worries.  I actually think your first answer was the best.  Looking at the source to that plugin, it's very well done.

Comment: Yes exactly, it's nice, but the OP asked for no plugins as you have probably noticed so implemented both :)

Comment: @Mark thank you so much this is very clear and easy to follow I appreciate that very much!