# Keep a list of checkboxes loaded for multiple selection

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, multipleselection

I followed a solution ["dropdown menu on click"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813177/d3-simple-drop-down-menu-on-click/35814318), many thanks to **@thisOneGuy**. I make it possible to appear a list of checkboxes by left-clicking on a `<rect>` area. But I got an issue that everytime when I click one of the checkboxes, the whole list would disappear. If I want to do multiple selection, I have to left click again.

Below is the code. I delete the unnecessary part and only leave the useful part to simplify the description:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <ul class='custom-menu'>
        <li data-action="first"><input type="checkbox"> First thing</li>
        <li data-action="second"><input type="checkbox">Second thing</li>
        <li data-action="both"><input type="checkbox">Third thing</li>
    </ul>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <svg id="svg2">
                <g id="layer1">
                    ...
                    <rect id="rect3643" style="stroke:#000000;stroke-width:.98070;fill:none" rx="4.5514" ry="3.1535" height="24.137" width="15.424" y="494.5" x="376.52" />
                    ...
                </g> 
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
.custom-menu {
    display: none;
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background: #FFF;
    color: #333;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.custom-menu li {
    padding: 8px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.custom-menu li:hover {
    background-color: #DEF;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var rects = d3.selectAll("rect");
    rects.on("click", function(event) {

        // Avoid the real one
       d3.event.preventDefault();
    
        // Show contextmenu
        $(".custom-menu").finish().toggle(100).
    
        // In the right position (the mouse)
        css({
          top: d3.event.pageY + "px",
          left: d3.event.pageX + "px"
        });
      });

      // If the document is clicked somewhere
    $(document).bind("mousedown", function(e) {

    // If the clicked element is not the menu
    if (!$(e.target).parents(".custom-menu").length > 0) {
  
      // Hide it
      $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
    }
  });

  // If the menu element is clicked
    $(".custom-menu li").click(function() {

    // This is the triggered action name
    switch ($(this).attr("data-action")) {
  
      // A case for each action. Your actions here
      case "first":
        polygonClicked("first");
        break;
      case "second":
        polygonClicked("second");
        break;
      case "both":
        polygonClicked("first");
        polygonClicked("second");
        break;
    }
  
    // Hide it AFTER the action was triggered
    $(".custom-menu").hide(100);
  });
});
```

I didn't change too much on css and made some modification in JS. The function `polygonClicked(e)` is a function I wrote to change background of other polygons.

Could someone help me to make the list possible for multiple selection and only disappear when I click outside the area of the list?

Comment: Hi, Try removing this line `$(".custom-menu").hide(100);` which is at last in the code you shared.

Comment: @YashMaheshwari It does not work. Oh that actually works! Awesome. Thanks for the tips. I delete the previous reply for removing wrong line.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the last line `$(".custom-menu").hide(100);` from the code you shared which hides the menu whenever click on a list item is made.